# Horizontal Scroll View (4 listview)

Tags: android, listview, scroll, scrollview

in my linear layout i have 2 listview's vertically oriented. So i want to add to the "second slide" two more listview's which are simmilar like those before.
When I open my app, first 2 listview which are vertically oriented will be shown, and then when I scroll to right another 2 listview will be shown.

And I tried do this with horizontal scroll, i had 2 linear layout in horizontal scroll view brackets. In first linear layout were first 2 listview's and in second linear layout were another two ...

And I got this in console: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child...

So, if I'm right, i can't have two linear layouts in HorizontalScrollView. Does anyone have another idea how to do it? I'm new in android, so i don't have any idea how to do it...

Thank you,
Matija :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, if I'm right, i can't have two linear layouts in HorizontalScrollView

That's correct, at least not two that are direct children of the `ScrollView` as the error message tells you.

You could, however, wrap those two `LinearLayout`s in a `LinearLayout` (sounds like with horizontal orientation though I'm having trouble picturing what you are doing).

If you could explain a little better what you are trying to accomplish (maybe with an image) then we may be able to give you a better suggestion. Sounds like fragments and/or `ViewPager` might work better for you. Either way, this should solve your problem.

Pictorially:

**You can't have this**

```
          ScrollView
         /          \
LinearLayout      LinearLayout
```

**You can have this**

```
          ScrollView
              |  
          LinearLayout   
             / \
 LinearLayout   LinearLayout
```